# Application build error phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create hello world application for android using phonegap and I am just beginning phonegap development. I have setup environment variables and done everything the project is also created but when i run then i get following error

```
D:\hello\example\fuckhead>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
'C:\Users\Ram' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
   [error] cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Have you come across such problem . Or if you have any idea why this error is causing then please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given ant build path in environment variables and also your sdk path. That both will do the wonder

Comment: I have set up three environment variables in System Varibale eg ANT_HOME, ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME and set them like ANT_HOME\bin , ANDROID_HOME\tools ,ANDROID_HOME\platform-tools and JAVA_HOME\bin..... as I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Please install cordova and run cordova create xxx com.example.xxx XXX. Den add android platform.  Same happened once fr me

Comment: I have installed node.js and then i installed cordova using npm install -g cordova and then i did cordova run but it said platform not added and now when i try to add i am getting same error actually even now